# webclient timeout while uploading

Tags: c#, file, upload, webclient

I know that WebClient doesnot have the property of timeout. I searched around and found different codes in which you can inherit the webclient from httpwebrequest and set the timeout For Example:

```
   class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).KeepAlive = false;
            (request as HttpWebRequest).Timeout = 25000; //(tried different values)
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

But nothing seems to work here. The timeout occurs exactly after 100 seconds. I am trying to upload big file through this client application i made. PHP is running on the server side and all timeouts/maxupload values are set.

The exception message is :

```
the request was aborted the request was canceled
```

Please help me out.

Comment: if keepalive is true do you get the same issue. False can send a connection close header to the server

Answer (score 3):

The code in the other answer worked for me, I only changed line 9 to:

```
((HttpWebRequest)request).Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
```

Comment: `(<value> as <type>).<something>` is a very bad practice; if `<value>` is not of type `<type>`, it will throw a `NullReferenceException`, which isn't helpful at all when diagnosing a problem. Use a direct cast instead: `((HttpWebRequest)request).Timeout`

Answer (score 0):

The default value of httpWebRequest is 100 seconds so something is not getting set right in the code.

Have you tried to set `.KeepAlive = true;`

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive.aspx) says setting it to false can

> When using HTTP/1.1, Keep-Alive is on by default. Setting KeepAlive to false may result in sending a Connection: Close header to the server.

This would make sense since it seems that you are setting your timeout correctly. You can doublecheck [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459241/httpwebrequest-the-request-was-aborted-the-request-was-canceled) SO question also has an answer that links that error message to the keep alive property.