# Converting async/await to Task.ContinueWith

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

This question was triggered by comments to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21326957/1768303):

How to back-port a non-linear `async/await` code to .NET 4.0 without `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`?

In the linked question, we have a `WebRequest` operation we want to retry for a limited number of times, if it keeps failing. The `Async/await` code could look like this:

```
async Task<HttpWebResponse> GetResponseWithRetryAsync(string url, int retries)
{
    if (retries < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    while (true)
    {
        WebResponse task = null;
        try
        {
            task = request.GetResponseAsync();
            return (HttpWebResponse)await task;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
                throw;

            if (--retries == 0)
                throw; // rethrow last error

            // otherwise, log the error and retry
            Debug.Print("Retrying after error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

From the first thought, I'd use `TaskCompletionSource`, as something like this (untested):

```
Task<HttpWebResponse> GetResponseWithRetryAsync(string url, int retries)
{
    if (retries < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    var request = WebRequest.Create(url);

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpWebResponse>();

    Action<Task<WebResponse>> proceesToNextStep = null;

    Action doStep = () =>
        request.GetResponseAsync().ContinueWith(proceedToNextStep);

    proceedToNextStep = (prevTask) =>
    {
        if (prevTask.IsCanceled)
            tcs.SetCanceled();
        else if (!prevTask.IsFaulted)
            tcs.SetResult((HttpWebResponse)prevTask.Result);
        else if (--retries == 0)
            tcs.SetException(prevTask.Exception);
        else
            doStep();
    };

    doStep();

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

The question is, **how to do this without `TaskCompletionSource`?**

Comment: Also `GetResponseAsync` didn't exist in .NET 4, you would have to use the older `BeginGetResponse`/`EndGetResponse`.

Comment: @mikez, true, I addressed it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21346870/1768303).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've figured out how to do it without `async/await` or `TaskCompletionSource`, using nested tasks and `Task.Unwrap` instead.

First, to address @mikez's comment, here's `GetResponseAsync` implementation for .NET 4.0:

```
static public Task<WebResponse> GetResponseTapAsync(this WebRequest request)
{
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(
         (asyncCallback, state) =>
             request.BeginGetResponse(asyncCallback, state),
         (asyncResult) =>
             request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult), null);
}
```

Now, here's `GetResponseWithRetryAsync` implementation:

```
static Task<HttpWebResponse> GetResponseWithRetryAsync(string url, int retries)
{
    if (retries < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    var request = WebRequest.Create(url);

    Func<Task<WebResponse>, Task<HttpWebResponse>> proceedToNextStep = null;

    Func<Task<HttpWebResponse>> doStep = () =>
    {
        return request.GetResponseTapAsync().ContinueWith(proceedToNextStep).Unwrap();
    };

    proceedToNextStep = (prevTask) =>
    {
        if (prevTask.IsCanceled)
            throw new TaskCanceledException();

        if (prevTask.IsFaulted && --retries > 0)
            return doStep();

        // throw if failed or return the result
        return Task.FromResult((HttpWebResponse)prevTask.Result);
    };

    return doStep();
}
```

It's been an interesting exercise. It works, but I think its the way more difficult to follow, than the `async/await` version.

Comment: +1 for this .NET 4 answer. The question this stemmed from was using the .NET 4.5+ implementation of WebRequest, which is unavailable, as it would eventually be made a PCL restricted to .NET 4.

Comment: FYI, Task.FromResult() is a .NET 4.5 method.

Comment: @DanielPark, a good point about `Task.FromResult`. This brings back `TaskCompletionSource` to simulate `Task.FromResult`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14244239/1768303